# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and ' float'

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

This is my code

```py
import datetime

from django.utils import timezone


class Allcourses(models.Model):
    started_from = models.DateTimeField('Started from')

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.started_from >= (timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).timestamp()
```

It shows:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and ' float'

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

`.timestamp()` gives a number for the epoch time (time since Jan 1970).  Remove that, so you can compare datetimes.

Comment: When I remove .timestamp() it shows "Expected type 'timedelta', got 'DateTimeField' instead .

Comment: Do you have `USE_TZ=True` in your `settings`?  If not, use `datetime.now()`

Comment: Yes , I have USE_TZ=True in settings. Then what next ?

Comment: Try `return self.started_from >= (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1))`

Comment: It shows '>=' not supported between instances of 'Nonetype' and 'datetime.datetime' .

Comment: How are you calling `was_published_recently`?